Fields that fill in automatically
I want to create a point layer with an ID field that fills in automatically as I digitize a geometry. It's possible? How can I do?

Yes, it is.
Go to Layer properties, attribute form, select the field of your ID, set default value to $id


I tried to set as you showed but when I added geometries the field returned the same value (0) for each element added.

what data type is your field? And does it show (0) after saving the layer and ending digitizing mode?

The data type is NUMBER (INTEGER). Yes, it shows 0 for each row after saving the layer and ending digitizing mode.

$id returns the feature id of the current row, it is not an ID generator. If you are going to use it as an id, you should impose the 'unique' and 'not null' coinstraints. Or you could use uuid() to generate a universally unique identifier, or perhaps  sqlite_fetch_and_increment(() bhut this is more complex. Another alternative is to create your own increment using something like coalesce(maximum(myID),0)+1. Apply  'unique' and 'not null' coinstraints for all intended ID fields.
